# Javax validation for List<String> throws exception

Tags: java, dto, bean-validation

I am trying to include a @Pattern validation for string elements inside a list using javax validation. Below is the simplified example:

```
public class ProgramRQDTO implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1L;

    @Size(min = 2, max= 5)
    private String lang;

    private List<@Pattern(regexp="^[a-zA-Z_]+$") String> destinations;

    ...getters/setters

}
```

This DTO is used as the body of a POST request in which the @Valid annotation is used.

```
@POST
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public Response method(@Valid @RequestBody MyDTO requestDto) {

    ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
    Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
    Set<ConstraintViolation<MyDTO>> violations = validator.validate(requestDto);

    ...

}
```

This method, **validator.validate(requestDto)**, throws an exception.

`javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000187: When using type annotation constraints on parameterized iterables or map @Valid must be used. Check com.example.MyDTO#destinations`

Is it possible to validate a List inside a DTO without having to make a wrapper class for that list? Is there something I am doing wrong?

Any help is appreciated.

I have tried to include the @Valid annotation in the DTO at different points but I have not been able to get rid of this error.

**UPDATE:**

All of the following give the same result:

@Valid

private List<@Pattern(regexp="^[a-zA-Z_]+$") String> destinations;

private List<@Valid @Pattern(regexp="^[a-zA-Z_]+$") String> destinations;

@Valid

private List<@Valid@Pattern(regexp="^[a-zA-Z_]+$") String> destinations;

Comment: Hello, I would just follow the error message and add the @Valid annotation to the field destinations in your DTO. I guess it was necessary in older versions of Java validation. Prior to Jakarta Bean Validation 3.O

Comment: Did you annotate `destinations` with `@Valid` like the message indicated?

Comment: Hi, yes, a tried with @Valid before List<String> and inside the List<@Valid ... String>. But same exception

Comment: Did you try to place the @Pattern rule annotation above the List<String>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just follow the error message and add the @Valid annotation to the field `destinations` in your DTO. I guess it was necessary in older versions of Java validation. Prior to Jakarta Bean Validation 3.O

**Solution**

Try this:

```
public class ProgramRQDTO implements Serializable {

    @Valid
    private List<@Pattern(regexp="^[a-zA-Z_]+$") String> destinations;

}
```

**EDIT** what I found on the net:

```
@Getter(onMethod = @__(@Valid))
@Setter(onParam = @__(@Valid))
@Valid
public class ProgramRQDTO implements Serializable {

    @Valid
    private List<@Pattern(regexp="^[a-zA-Z_]+$") String> destinations;

}
```

**EDIT 2**

I have just tested it with the newest versions of Spring Boot Starters and it works without any issues. No need of additional annotations. Following dependencies did the trick:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried to include the @Valid annotation in the DTO at different points but I have not been able to get rid of this error.
I tried before the List<String ...> and inside List<@Valid ... String>

Comment: Please check my edit. It looks like it is related to Lombok.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The problem as you say seems to be related to lombok, Unfortunately I can't use spring in this project but it gives me a clue where to look. Thanks